# MBprogressHUD not showing as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, mbprogresshud

I am using [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to show a HUD but it is not showing as expected.

Steps:
User selects a cell in a `tableView`. Some data is parsed then a warning (`UIAlertView`) is shown to the user. The user is asked if they want to create a New Game with the selected (cell) user. Cancel/Start Game buttons.

The `UIAlertView` delegate methods is as follows:

## pragma mark - UIAlertView Delegate

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"button %i",buttonIndex);
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // Cancel button pressed
        self.gameNewOpponentuser = nil;
    } else {
        // Start Game button pressed
        [MESGameModel createNewGameWithUser:[PFUser currentUser] against:self.gameNewOpponentuser];
    }
}
```

If the user selects Start Game the `GameModel` method is run. The game model(`NSObject` subclass) method is as follows:

## pragma mark - Custom method

```
+(void)createNewGameWithUser:(PFUser *)user1 against:(PFUser *)user2 {
    // First we put a HUD up for the user on the window
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDCreateNewGame", @"HUD - Create New Game text");
    HUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    
    // Confirm we have two users to play with.
    
}
```

As you can see the HUD is alloc init to the keywindow of the application. However, the HUD is not showing as expected, nothing happens no UI lockup etc. I have put a breakpoint in the above method and can see that it is called however the HUD is not displayed

From the above, I expect the HUD to show up but nothing else happen, i.e. the HUD just remain on screen at the moment...

Comment: NOTE: Flagged to be removed or allow me to answer my own question. THIS IS NOW RESOLVED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. I was using `clickedButtonAtIndex` method for the `UIAlertView` which was of course holding to the view. I used `didDismissWithButtonIndex` instead and this works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the part where you add the HUD to the `Window` and then showing the HUD. Note that you can add the HUD to the `Window` or the current view (`self.view`).

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:HUD]; //<-- You're missing this

HUD.dimBackground = YES;
HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDCreateNewGame", @"HUD - Create New Game text");
HUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;

[HUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{ //<-- And this
  // Do something
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not make the HUD show either :( The alert view is dismissed the method is called just the HUD does not show?

Comment: Set this property to the HUD before displaying it: `HUD.minShowTime = 4.0; // in seconds`. Or make sure you DO something in the `executingBlock`

Comment: [HUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{ //<-- And this
  // Do something
}]; is this chunk of code necessary ? Why not only [self.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD show:YES];.

Comment: @G.Abhisek It is necessary if you want to show the animation only while that block is being executed, and hide the animation automatically when the block finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDCreateNewGame", @"HUD - Create New Game text");
// Set determinate mode
[HUD setMode:MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD show:YES];
```

Comment: As above, I am using a game model not a VC so cannot access self.view

Comment: which is your super class ?

Comment: Yes, that what I tried originally and doesnt work. I have also added [HUD show:YES]; and [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:HUD]; but not HUD is shown...

Comment: Which I guess is the question?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I was using clickedButtonAtIndex method for the UIAlertView which was of course holding to the view. I used didDismissWithButtonIndex instead and this works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding it to any view for it to be displayed. So add it to appropriate view.

From the git hub project demo for MBProgressHUD

```
// The hud will dispable all input on the view (use the higest view possible in the view hierarchy)
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
```

Comment: I am loading the HUD from a model therefore do not have access to self.navigationController.view...

Comment: Its a example. You need to add it to some view not necessarily of the navigation controller.

Comment: In my example I use window as its a model and would not have a view related to it. Its ok I found the answer now

Answer (score 0):

You are not given the code to display the hud. use the following code

```
 MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
 HUD.dimBackground = YES;
 HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDCreateNewGame", @"HUD - Create New Game text");
```

Comment: I cannot use self.view I am initiating it from a Model not a View Controller so wouldn't have access to self.view